# Solving ODE System and Estimating Parameters with Experimental Data

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

I am new to Mathematica. I am trying to find out the best-fit values of the parameters appearing in an ODE system of three equations.
The three ODE equations are:

```
{a'[t] == -k[1]*a[t], b'[t] == -k[2]*b[t] + k[1]*a[t], c'[t] == k[2]*b[t]}
```

The experimental data set for the three equations with respect to time (in minutes) is:

```
adata = {{0, 1}, {2, 0.88}, {6, .69}, {10, .53}, {20, .28}, {30, .15}, {50, .043}, {70, .012}, {90, 0}, {120, 0}, {150, 0}, {200, 0}}
bdata = {{0, 0}, {2, 0.12}, {6, .29}, {10, .42}, {20, .56}, {30, .57}, {50, .46}, {70, .33}, {90, 0.22}, {120, 0.12}, {150, .06}, {200, 0.02}}
cdata = {{0, 0}, {2, 0.003}, {6, .030}, {10, .050}, {20, .16}, {30, .28}, {50, .50}, {70, .66}, {90, 0.78}, {120, 0.88}, {150, .94}, {200, 0.98}}
```

(First entry in each pair is time)
The goal here is to solve ODE, and then optimize the parameters (k1, k2) such that the equations can best describe the experimental data.
I would be very thankful to you, if you can spare some of your valuable time and help me with this query. 
the objective fuction to be minimzed is as follows

[image]
But it is giving me the error like 'not a real number' etc.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  I have edited your post the way we like to see things.  Note that we have entered all equations and data in properly formatted code blocks with proper Mathematica syntax.  This way, we can copy and paste your code into our own copies of Mathematica without having to write it all out ourselves.

Comment: @march thank you for editing my post.

Comment: @morbo,  or any body else could you please see why the Functionn 'SS' is giving error when evaluated through FindMinimum or NMinimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

adata = {{0, 1}, {2, 0.88}, {6, .69}, {10, .53}, {20, .28}, {30, .15}, {50, .043}, {70, .012}, {90, 0}, {120, 0}, {150, 0}, {200, 0}};
bdata = {{0, 0}, {2, 0.12}, {6, .29}, {10, .42}, {20, .56}, {30, .57}, {50, .46}, {70, .33}, {90, 0.22}, {120, 0.12}, {150, .06}, {200, 0.02}};
cdata = {{0, 0}, {2, 0.003}, {6, .030}, {10, .050}, {20, .16}, {30, .28}, {50, .50}, {70, .66}, {90, 0.78}, {120, 0.88}, {150, .94}, {200, 0.98}};

eqns = {a'[t] == -k1 a[t], b'[t] == -k2 b[t] + k1 a[t],  c'[t] == k2 b[t]};
Thread[{aa[t_], bb[t_], cc[t_]} = DSolveValue[{eqns, a[0] == 1, b[0] == 0, c[0] == 0}, {a[t], b[t],  c[t]}, t]];



model[k1_, k2_] := Sum[(aa[adata[[i, 1]]] - adata[[i, 2]])^2 + (bb[bdata[[i, 1]]] - 
    bdata[[i, 2]])^2 + (cc[cdata[[i, 1]]] - cdata[[i, 2]])^2, {i, Length@adata}]        


 fit = Last@ NMinimize[model[k1, k2], {k1, k2}]
```

> {k1 -> 0.0632016, k2 -> 0.0211064}

```
Thread[{k1, k2} = Values@fit];

Show[Plot[{aa[t], bb[t], cc[t]}, {t, 0, 200}, Frame -> True], ListPlot[{adata, bdata, cdata}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @OkkesDulgerci, That was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, when you have data points, always plot and have a look at it.

I replaced your `k[1]` and `k[2]` with $ \delta $ and $ \alpha $.

```
eqns = {a'[t] == -k[1]*a[t], b'[t] == -k[2]*b[t] + k[1]*a[t], c'[t] == k[2]*b[t]} /. {k[1] -> \[Delta], k[2] -> \[Alpha]} 

ListLinePlot[{adata, bdata, cdata}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: plot]

Looks like a bunch of $a e^{x}$ functions to me...And your system of equations is small, they may have an analytical solution.

```
DSolve[{eqns, a[0] == 1, b[0] == 0, c[0] == 0}, {a[t], c[t], b[t]}, t]
```

$$ \left\{\left\{a(t)\to e^{\delta  (-t)},b(t)\to -\frac{\delta  e^{\alpha  (-t)-\delta  t} \left(e^{\delta  t}-e^{\alpha  t}\right)}{\alpha -\delta },c(t)\to \frac{e^{\alpha  (-t)-\delta  t} \left(\alpha  e^{\alpha  t+\delta  t}-\delta  e^{\alpha  t+\delta  t}-\alpha  e^{\alpha  t}+\delta  e^{\delta  t}\right)}{\alpha -\delta }\right\}\right\}. $$

Oh, they do. We're in luck! We can write a simple manipulate for fitting.

```
Manipulate[Plot[{E^(-t \[Delta]), -((E^(-t \[Alpha] - t \[Delta]) (-E^(t \[Alpha]) + E^(t \[Delta])) \[Delta])/(\[Alpha] - \[Delta])), (E^(-t \[Alpha] - t \[Delta]) (-E^(t \[Alpha]) \[Alpha] + E^(t \[Alpha] + t \[Delta]) \[Alpha] + E^(t \[Delta]) \[Delta] - E^(t \[Alpha] + t \[Delta]) \[Delta]))/(\[Alpha] - \[Delta])}, {t, 0.1, 199}, Epilog -> {{Red, Point[adata]}, {Blue, Point[bdata]}, {Green, Point[cdata]}}, ImageSize -> Large], {{\[Delta], 0.0613}, 0.0001, 0.08}, {{\[Alpha], 0.02085}, 0.0001, 0.03} ]
```

[image: manupulate]

We've found by hand some good initial values for $\delta$ and $\alpha$

We can use this as initial values for a nonlinear model fit.

```
m1 = NonlinearModelFit[
  adata, {a[t]} /. sol, {{\[Delta], 0.0613}, {\[Alpha], 0.02085}}, t]
m2 = NonlinearModelFit[
  bdata, {b[t]} /. sol, {{\[Delta], 0.0613}, {\[Alpha], 0.02085}}, t]
m3 = NonlinearModelFit[
  cdata, {c[t]} /. sol, {{\[Delta], 0.0613}, {\[Alpha], 0.02085}}, t]
```

Plot the result

```
Plot[{m1[t], m2[t], m3[t]}, {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> {{Red, Point[adata]}, {Blue, Point[bdata]}, {Green, 
    Point[cdata]}}]
```

[image: new plot]

and then get some infos about our parameters that `NonlinearModelfit` found.

```
m1["ParameterTable"]
m2["ParameterTable"]
m3["ParameterTable"]
```

$$ \begin{array}{l|llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{t-Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
\hline
 \delta  & 0.063221 & 0.000225209 & 280.722 & \text{8.092528367214482$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-21} \\
 \alpha  & 0.02085 & 0. & \infty  & \text{0$\grave{ }\grave{ }$323.6072453387798} \\
\end{array} $$

$$ \begin{array}{l|llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{t-Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
\hline
 \delta  & 0.0629746 & 0.000365423 & 172.333 & \text{1.0634929126057997$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-18} \\
 \alpha  & 0.0210366 & 0.0000895516 & 234.91 & \text{4.805391875551799$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-20} \\
\end{array} $$

$$ \begin{array}{l|llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{t-Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
\hline
 \delta  & 0.0640477 & 0.00221151 & 28.961 & \text{5.61521578981255$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-11} \\
 \alpha  & 0.0210622 & 0.000314458 & 66.9795 & \text{1.3404461637525215$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-14} \\
\end{array} $$

```
Histogram[m1["FitResiduals"]]
Histogram[m2["FitResiduals"]]
Histogram[m3["FitResiduals"]]
```

[image: histo]

Comment: Thank you @morbo. Can you please clarify to me that this 'Manipulate' does the same job as 'FindMinimum' or 'NMinimize' in terms of regressing to get best-fit parameters? Also how do I upvote, I cant see a button?

Comment: what are the values we got for parameters δ and α? I actually need these values for further input in another software.

Comment: If you click on the plus beaide the slider you‘ll get the values i found playing around. I will answer the rest later when i‘m on my computer...$\delta=0.0631$ and $\alpha=0.02085$

Comment: @wahab the blue arrows up and down beside my answer and the grey check mark is there too

Comment: Thank you @morbo. Done.

Comment: Hello @morbo, could you please also solve this problem with 'NMinimize' and 'FindMinimum' functions? Your previous feedback was very helpful to me. As I am new in mathematica, I will save your code for my future reference. Many Thanks

Comment: @wahab see update, I used Nonlinearmodelfit, as it plays better for what you're looking for I think. Though the hand values are good enough I think.

Answer (score 0):

Using the language resources

```
adata = {{0, 1}, {2, 0.88}, {6, .69}, {10, .53}, {20, .28}, {30, .15}, {50, .043}, {70, .012}, {90, 0}, {120, 0}, {150, 0}, {200, 0}};
bdata = {{0, 0}, {2, 0.12}, {6, .29}, {10, .42}, {20, .56}, {30, .57}, {50, .46}, {70, .33}, {90, 0.22}, {120, 0.12}, {150, .06}, {200, 0.02}};
cdata = {{0, 0}, {2, 0.003}, {6, .030}, {10, .050}, {20, .16}, {30, .28}, {50, .50}, {70, .66}, {90, 0.78}, {120, 0.88}, {150, .94}, {200, 0.98}};
adata0 = Table[Flatten[{1, adata[[k]]}], {k, 1, Length[adata]}];
bdata0 = Table[Flatten[{2, bdata[[k]]}], {k, 1, Length[adata]}];
cdata0 = Table[Flatten[{3, cdata[[k]]}], {k, 1, Length[adata]}];
transformedData = Join[Join[adata0, bdata0], cdata0];

tmax = 200;
eqns = {a'[t] == -k1*a[t], a[0] == a0, b'[t] == -k2*b[t] + k1*a[t], b[0] == b0, c'[t] == k2*b[t], c[0] == c0};
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, {a, b, c}, {t, 0, tmax}, {k1, k2, a0, b0, c0}];

model[k1_, k2_, a0_, b0_, c0_][i_, t_] := Through[sol[k1, k2, a0, b0, c0][t], List][[i]] /; And @@ NumericQ /@ {k1, k2, a0, b0, c0, i, t};
fit = NonlinearModelFit[transformedData, model[k1, k2, a0, b0, c0][i, t], {k1, k2, a0, b0, c0}, {i, t}] // Quiet;

fit["ParameterTable"]
```

obtaining the results

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{t-Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
 \text{k1} & 0.0630922 & 0.000256218 & 246.244 & \text{1.358897$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-52} \\
 \text{k2} & 0.0210129 & 0.0000735043 & 285.874 & \text{1.3335103$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-54} \\
 \text{a0} & 0.99959 & 0.00160667 & 622.151 & \text{4.545291$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-65} \\
 \text{b0} & 0.000233603 & 0.00172373 & 0.135522 & 0.893075 \\
 \text{c0} & 0.00247035 & 0.00120983 & 2.04189 & 0.0497497 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: You can use `a[0]==1,b[0]==0,c[0]==0` from data..

Comment: I know that but I prefer to consider the model as stated because it is more general and can be applied to other dynamic systems. The data could contain noise as well.